# cx_Oracle: Connection keep alive

Tags: cx-oracle

I have a program which uses cx_Oracle and receives a really large number of logs in chunks, and for each chunk does all kinds of calculations before getting the next chunk.

One of the calculations can sometimes be very long (nothing I can do with it, data is sent to a remote server), and then I might lose the connection.

How can I keep the connection alive without messing up the fetching?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Have the same here, a firewall terminates the connection towards the client (not the database). I tried a thread that executes "executeSQL('select * from dual')" in intervals, but when the calculation in the main thread starts, the executeSQL() isn't executed until the calculation has finished.